# LibGdx Make a body jump

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I have wrote the following code to make a body jump and several other things but the problem is that the body is only jumping up to certain limit and moreover only the player body is not effected by gravity in a way it should be so I increased gravity scale to 100
Please give a solution to jump and gravity

```
public class Shoot implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;
    private short x, y;
    private float g;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private ChainShape groundshape;
    private BodyDef bdef;
    private FixtureDef fdef;
    private Body player;
    private PolygonShape pshape;
    private CircleShape cshape;
    private Vector2 v;
    private ArrayList<Body> d;
    private ArrayList<Body> bullet;
    private Sprite bsprite;
    private boolean right = true;
    private Body enemy;
    private byte l = 3;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        d = new ArrayList<Body>();
        bullet = new ArrayList<Body>();
        dimensions();
        camera();
        renderer();
        world();
        batch();
        input();
        ground();
        player();
        enemy();
        collisions();
        bricks(4, -6);
        sprites();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        pshape.dispose();
        cshape.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        world.step(1 / 60f, 8, 3);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < bullet.size(); i++) {
            bsprite.setPosition(
                    bullet.get(i).getPosition().x - bsprite.getWidth() / 2f,
                    bullet.get(i).getPosition().y - bsprite.getHeight() / 2f);
            if (bullet.get(i).getLinearVelocity().y == 200)
                bsprite.rotate90(false);
            bsprite.draw(batch);
        }
        batch.end();
        for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
            world.destroyBody(d.get(i));
            d.remove(i);
            i -= 1;
        }
        player.setLinearVelocity(v);

        camera.position.x = player.getPosition().x;
        camera.update();
        renderer.render(world, camera.combined);

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width / 25f;
        camera.viewportHeight = height / 25f;
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    private void world() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);

    }

    private void dimensions() {
        x = (short) Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        y = (short) Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        g = (float) ((y * 14 / 720f) * (6 / 7f));
    }

    private void renderer() {
        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    }

    private void camera() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(x / 25f, y / 25f);

    }

    private void batch() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    private void input() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {

            @Override
            public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer,
                    int button) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer,
                    int button) {

                bullet();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
                if (keycode == Keys.D || keycode == Keys.A) {
                    v.x = 0;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                if (keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) {
                    Gdx.app.exit();
                }
                if (keycode == Keys.D) {
                    v.x = 15;
                    right = true;
                }
                if (keycode == Keys.A) {
                    v.x = -15f;
                    right = false;
                }
                if (keycode == Keys.SPACE) {
                    player.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 50000),
                            player.getLocalCenter(), true);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void ground() {
        bdef = new BodyDef();
        bdef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bdef.allowSleep = true;
        groundshape = new ChainShape();
        groundshape.createChain(new Vector2[] { new Vector2(-x, -g),
                new Vector2(x, -g) });
        fdef = new FixtureDef();
        fdef.shape = groundshape;
        fdef.restitution = 0f;
        fdef.friction = 0f;
        fdef.density = 0.5f;
        world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef);
        groundshape.dispose();
    }

    private void player() {
        v = new Vector2(0, 0);
        bdef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bdef.allowSleep = true;
        bdef.fixedRotation = true;
        bdef.gravityScale = 100;
        bdef.position.x = 0f;
        bdef.position.y = -g + 2f;
        pshape = new PolygonShape();
        pshape.setAsBox(1, 2);
        fdef.shape = pshape;
        fdef.friction = 0f;
        fdef.restitution = 0f;
        fdef.density = 1f;
        player = world.createBody(bdef);
        player.createFixture(fdef);
        cshape = new CircleShape();
        cshape.setPosition(new Vector2(0, 3.1f));
        cshape.setRadius(1f);
        fdef.shape = cshape;
        player.createFixture(fdef);
    }

    private void bricks(float x, float y) {
        bdef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bdef.allowSleep = true;
        bdef.position.x = x;
        bdef.position.y = y;
        fdef.density = 0.5f;
        fdef.restitution = 0f;
        pshape.setAsBox(3, 1);
        fdef.shape = pshape;
        fdef.friction = 0f;
        world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef);

    }

    private void collisions() {
        world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

            @Override
            public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

            }

            @Override
            public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
                if (contact.getFixtureA().getShape().getType() == cshape
                        .getType()
                        || contact.getFixtureB().getShape().getType() == cshape
                                .getType()) {
                    v.y = 0;
                }
                if (contact.getFixtureA().getBody().isBullet()) {
                    d.add(contact.getFixtureA().getBody());
                    bullet.remove(bullet.indexOf(contact.getFixtureA()
                            .getBody()));
                }
                if (contact.getFixtureB().getBody().isBullet()) {
                    d.add(contact.getFixtureB().getBody());
                    bullet.remove(bullet.indexOf(contact.getFixtureB()
                            .getBody()));
                }
                if ((contact.getFixtureA().getBody().equals(enemy) && contact
                        .getFixtureB().getBody().isBullet())
                        || contact.getFixtureB().getBody().equals(enemy)
                        && contact.getFixtureA().getBody().isBullet()) {
                    enemy.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
                    l--;
                    if (l == 0) {
                        d.add(enemy);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void endContact(Contact contact) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void bullet() {
        bdef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bdef.allowSleep = true;
        bdef.bullet = true;
        bdef.fixedRotation = true;
        bdef.gravityScale = 0;
        pshape.setAsBox(0.25f, 0.15f);
        if (right && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            bdef.position.x = player.getPosition().x + 1.6f;
            bdef.position.y = player.getPosition().y + 1f;

        } else if (!right && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            bdef.position.x = player.getPosition().x - 1.6f;
            bdef.position.y = player.getPosition().y + 1f;

        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            bdef.position.x = player.getPosition().x;
            bdef.position.y = player.getPosition().y + 4.5f;
            pshape.setAsBox(0.15f, 0.25f);

        }
        fdef.density = 0.4f;
        fdef.shape = pshape;
        fdef.restitution = 0f;
        fdef.friction = 0f;
        bullet.add(world.createBody(bdef));
        bullet.get(bullet.size() - 1).createFixture(fdef);
        if (right && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            bullet.get(bullet.size() - 1).setLinearVelocity(50, 0);
        } else if (!right && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            bullet.get(bullet.size() - 1).setLinearVelocity(-50, 0);

        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            bullet.get(bullet.size() - 1).setLinearVelocity(0, 50);

        }

    }

    private void sprites() {
        bsprite = new Sprite(new Texture("data/bullet.jpg"));
        bsprite.setOrigin(bsprite.getWidth() / 2f, bsprite.getHeight() / 2f);
        bsprite.rotate(0);
        bsprite.setSize(0.5f, 0.30f);
    }

    private void enemy() {
        bdef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bdef.allowSleep = true;
        bdef.fixedRotation = true;
        bdef.gravityScale = 100;
        bdef.position.x = 7f;
        bdef.position.y = -g + 2f;
        pshape = new PolygonShape();
        pshape.setAsBox(1, 2);
        fdef.shape = pshape;
        fdef.friction = 0f;
        fdef.restitution = 0f;
        fdef.density = 1f;
        enemy = world.createBody(bdef);
        enemy.createFixture(fdef);
        cshape = new CircleShape();
        cshape.setPosition(new Vector2(0, 3));
        cshape.setRadius(1f);
        fdef.shape = cshape;
        enemy.createFixture(fdef);
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is really hard to read... Maybe you could reduce it a bit to the important parts?

Comment: @noone now it is reduced

Comment: Besides the removed imports, nothing has changed. Nobody will help you with this, if you just post 400 lines of completely undocumented code.

Comment: The problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

The use of player.setLinearVelocity() in the render method has hindered the motion of the body setting the linear velocity in y direction 0 always

Comment: @springrbua It is the answer As soon as I apply the impulse the setLinearVelocity() method in the render() method sets the velocity to 0 in all directions

Comment: Oh i am sorry. I missunderstood this. It sounded like it is another problem^^ Sorry for that!